# Appbar alignment

Tags: flutter, alignment, google-signin, appbar

I am looking to align the name of the user next to the Welcome Back Text. Is there any way that this can be done in one line of code? Here is what I have right now.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text("Welcome Back", style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 39, 79, 1), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              child: Text(
                name, style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 39, 79, 1), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20)
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  imageUrl,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for this case `Row(...)`

```
  actions: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Text(name, style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 39, 79, 1), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20))
        ),
        Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ]
```

Btw: You don't need `new`. It is since Dart 2.0 optional.

Comment: thank you but that fixes half of the problem. How do I get the name aligned to the other text? I've just tried to fix it with textAlign but that didn't work for me

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the title of the AppBar? EDIT: Check this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/TTSqPPU). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, how can I align the name closer to the "Welcome Back" text?

Comment: Well, just use `centerTitle: true` in `AppBar(...)`.